# How to match until first (element) using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, search, replace

Having:

```
queryBuilder.Append("openquery(SCHEMAA,'select * from SCHEMAA.SomeView') va, ");
queryBuilder.Append("openquery(SCHEMAB,'select * from SCHEMAB.ANOTHERVIEW') ve ");
```

I want to match until the first appearance of `(`.

I tried:

```
^.+\({1}
```

But it highlight until the last (:

```
queryBuilder.Append("openquery(
```

How can I do?

Comment: What language are you using? This,  in most languages would be a trivial string find operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` quantifier [is greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), which means that `.+` will match as much as possible. You could simply add the `?` quantifier after `.+` in order to make it lazy, `.+?`:

```
^.+?\(
```

Which would yield:

```
queryBuilder.Append(
```

However, a better approach is to use [a negated character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `[^(]`,  to match all characters except `(`:

```
^[^(]+
```

Which would yield:

```
queryBuilder.Append
```

And, of course, if you want to include the `(`, use `^[^(]+\(` instead.